# Do difficult native languages slow down early education?

Tags: language-acquisition, japanese, native-language

Do students from countries that teach native languages considered to be quite difficult (e.g. Japanese) generally take longer to master that language? Or does the power of being surrounded by a particular language at home and in society overcome the difficulty of said language? Are there simply too many factors that influence how well one student learns their native language compared to others?

Another thing: Is the 'difficulty' of a certain language considered completely relative to whatever languages someone already knows, or are some languages universally more difficult?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Linguistics. Also, questions on language learning have greater chance to receive good answers at [Language Learning.SE](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) Beta site.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I wasn't aware of the language learning site. I'll see what they have to say there

Comment: @bytebuster Many linguists work in language acquisition.

Comment: It's usually held that all children acquire their mother tongue with (roughly) equal ease. Languages vary in how difficult they are to acquire as a second language, but the level of difficulty depends on the first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All native speakers possess knowledge of at least spoken form of the language. But of course there can be difficult areas especially in written form. In Russian for instance, native speakers often experience problems with punctuation: where should or should not be placed a comma. This is quite difficult topic even for the well educated. Another difficult (but less difficult than punctuation) area is single vs. double "н" in spelling.